# Backup a directory to a destination already having an older backup?

Tags: files, rsync, backup

I would like to backup some directory on my laptop to an external hard drive.

The destination in the external hard drive already has an older backup of the directory on my laptop.

1. I was wondering how I can update the backup on my external hard
   drive? For example, will the following command work as expected?

   ```
   rsync -a --delete  /path/to/source/dir  /path/to/dest/dir
   ```

   does it work the same as I first `rm -r /path/to/dest/dir/*`, and then
   `rsync -a  /path/to/source/dir  /path/to/dest/dir`?
2. How can I make `rsync` create the new backup faster without making
   mistakes, by taking advantage of the older backup on the destination
   (some files might have been changed since the last backup, but more
   files haven't)? Another reason for taking advantage of the older backup is that my external hard drive doesn't have enough space to hold a new backup without removing anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to run a backup again with only files and directories which have changed since the last backup?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I want to backup all the current files and directories in an efficient way

Comment: If you just want to back up that directory to an external HD then you can just `cp -rv -f /laptop/directory /external/hdd/`. That will overwrite any older files whether they've changed or not without prompting.

Comment: But `cp` is not efficient, and can't take advantage of the older backup.

Comment: Then use a proper backup software such as borgbackup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. How can I make rsync create the new backup faster without making mistakes, by taking advantage of the older backup on the destination (some files might have been changed since the last backup, but more files haven't)?

Backing up with `rsync` does this by default, *if* you pass `-a` (and get the paths right, as per @xenoid's answer).  And you want to pass `-a` anyway, so it's all good.  The specific reason is a bit subtle:

> Rsync finds files that need to be transferred  using  a  "quick  check"
>          algorithm  (by  default) that looks for files that have changed in size
>          or  in  last-modified  time.

If rsync thinks a file doesn't need to be transferred, then it doesn't transfer it.  And this works because `-a` implies this option:

```
    -t, --times                 preserve modification times
```

so the last-modified time will be the *same* on the backup file as it is on the original file.

> without making mistakes

Just don't fake `rsync` out by modifying the contents of files and then resetting their last-modified time :-).  Otherwise that file will be overlooked.

I haven't heard of this being a problem, so I wouldn't worry about it. It's common to use `rsync` for basic backups in this way.

I expect it's more likely that you'd run into other limitations. I.e. if you back up $HOME without using filesystem snapshots, then your firefox profile is probably being modified at the same time as the backup runs, and you will not get a consistent working firefox profile in your backup. Or that you'll want to recover a deleted/overwritten file, but since you're not keeping any older backups, it could already have been deleted/overwritten on the backup.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if it is faster or slower using `-u` than not using `-u`? Does `-u` not make any mistake in determining which file to actually transfer? Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443829/what-differences-are-between-using-u-and-not-with-rsync

Comment: @Time It will not be faster. This is why I say it is subtle :-) - if you do *not* use `-a` / `-t`, then rsync will copy all files from scratch, unless you use `-u`. Do you see why? I would avoid using `-u` when you don't need to, as there are more cases where it would make a mistake. It can even skip files that are different sizes, if the source file has been dated backwards in time.

Comment: Bad idea to use `-u` for this... If you ever roll back a file to something of the same size with an earlier date, your backup will keep the most recent version, which is no longer the one you have.

Comment: @xenoid no, worse. `-u` says "This  forces rsync to skip any files which **exist** on the destination and have a modified time that  is  newer  than  the  source
              file." It doesn't matter if they are a different size or not.

Comment: Thanks. If `-u` decides a file required for transfer, does the quick check algorithm also decides the same?

Comment: @Tim No. If the file is not skipped by `-u`, then the destination file must be older *or the same time* as the source. If the destination file has the same date AND is the same size as the source, then the quick check algorithm will decide the file does not need to be transferred. (Note that when you pass `-u`, the quick check algorithm is still used to skip files with same time and size).

Comment: The reason the "quick check" is described as applying "by default", is that you can modify how it works with the `--size-only` option. In that case, it skips when the size matches, even if the time does not match.

Comment: if -u decides to transfer a file, then either the mtime of the file is older than the source file, or the mtime of the file is the same as that of the source file but their sizes are different. In either case, the quick check algorithm will also decide to transfer the file. Correct?

Comment: @Tim you asked about `-u` and the quick check algorithm as separate things. I think this is a confusing question because _when you pass -u, the quick check algorithm is still used to skip files with same time and size_. If `rsync -u` decides to transfer a file, then the quick check algorithm must have decided to transfer the file. IOW it's true that if `rsync -u` decides to transfer a file, then `rsync` will also decide the same.

Comment: Thanks. I think  -u and the quick check algorithm as separate things. Even if they work together by either OR or AND logical relation to decide if a file can be skipped, then it is always one of them that actually decides, because the other will always make the same decision

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `rsync` is a good solution, but better use (note the ending slashes):

```
rsync -a --delete  /path/to/source/dir/  /path/to/dest/dir/
```

To quote `man rsync`:

> A  trailing  slash  on  the  source changes this behavior to avoid creating an additional directory level at the destination.  You can think of a trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by name"[...]

With `--delete` you get mirroring (exact same files), without it you get additive backup (files deleted in the source are kept in the copy).

The danger of `--delete` is that if you target the wrong directory, many files can be deleted, so best restrict its use to well-tested scripts, or use `-n`/`--dry-run` to check first what would happen.

Comment: Or you could include `--max-delete 50` to (say) limit the number of deleted files to 50 per invocation.

Comment: Yes, but as far as my experiments go it still erases 50 files and only stops when it hits the 51st... And if you lower the threshold `--delete` is no longer very useful.

Comment: Of course. It's a safety valve on `--delete` "if you target the wrong directory".